# How do I make text bold AND italics at same time in base R plot?

Tags: r, string, plot, formatting, boxplot

Let's say I have a plot:

```
plot(1:5,1:5, main = "Plot Title here")
```

**How do I make my main title both bold and italic?**

I can make it bold *or* italic, but I've been unable to acheive both simultaneously.

```
main = expression(italic("Plot Title here"))          #makes italic
main = expression(bold("Plot Title here"))            #makes bold
main = expression(bold(italic("Plot Title here")))    #still only makes italic!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?plotmath`:

```r
main = expression(bolditalic("Plot Title here"))   
plot(1:5,1:5, main = main)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oy seriously?! I guess that makes sense. The more you know... :p. Thanks! (and thanks for the plotmath hint -- didn't know that existed)